# Three.js importing Blender Model. Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined

Tags: javascript, three.js, blender

I'm trying to import a 3d model from Blender to a Three.js project, but I still get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'x' of undefined.  This is the piece of code that creates the problem:

```
var loader= new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('http://localhost/js/map.json', function(geometry) {
 mesh= new THREE.Mesh(geometry);
 scene.add(mesh);
});
```

And here you can find the json of the 3d model that was provided to me:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=14990264909497963783

Any help to understand what does not work will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use the JSON Blender exporter anymore. It's was removed several releases ago. Export your models as `glTF` and use `GLTFLoader` for loading. Read the following guide for more information: https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#manual/en/introduction/Loading-3D-models

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to create a `Mesh()` without a material. You should be passing a material as the second argument of its constructor, like this:

```
var loader= new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load('http://localhost/js/map.json', function(geometry) {
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffff00 } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);
});
```

You can read about creating a [Mesh object in the documents](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Mesh). And as Mugen87 said, it's recommended you use the `.gltf` exporter instead of `JSON` because JSON has been deprecated.